# Is there a Physics Exchange Career 2.0?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that stack overflow as an advertised career 2.0. I assume users on that site receive some type of career boost? Is there an equivalent for Physics Exchange? If not, could we make one?

Comment: No and I really doubt something similar is possible.

Answer (score 5):

Careers 2.0 is an exclusive place for those with good Stack Overflow / GitHub profiles, where employers can put job listings from this pool of "good" candidates.

Employment in physics works very differently, and besides our community is small, so I doubt it would work.

Comment: I am not aware of any employment in physics. Do you have examples of employment in physics?

Comment: @linuxfreebird Applying for a professor is very different from applying for a programming job. For example, IT companies recruit. Universities ... not so much.  Add to that the level of specialization required, and the model becomes totally unfeasible.

Comment: What about building an academic resume for graduate school?

Comment: That's totally different, and is usually handled within the institute (pretty well, too). Also, there's no monetization opportunity there, and the marginal gain to the community isn't much.

Comment: What are examples of how the community gains from something?